# Question about void functions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I know my code is correct except one thing. After I enter the first weekly salary, everything is displayed. But when I go to enter another weekly salary, the FWI, FICA & NET PAY does not show.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

//function prototypes
void getSalary(double &salary);
void calcFedTaxes(double salary, double FWT_RATE, double FICA_RATE, double &fwt, double &fica);
void calcNetPay(double salary, double fwt, double fica, double &netPay);
void displayInfo(double fwt, double fica, double netPay);

int main()
{
    //declare constants and variables
    const double .2;
    const double FICA_RATE = .08;
    double salary = 0;
    double fwt    = 0;
    double fica   = 0;
    double netPay = 0;

    //get salary
    getSalary(salary);

    //calculate the federal taxes
    calcFedTaxes(salary, FWT_RATE, FICA_RATE, fwt, fica);

    //calculate net pay
    calcNetPay(salary, fwt, fica, netPay);

    //display , gross, taxes, and net
    displayInfo(fwt, fica, netPay);

    while (salary != 0)
    {
        cout << "Weekly salary: ";
        cin >> salary;
    }    //end while

    return 0;
} //end of main function

//*****function definitions*****

void getSalary(double &salary)
{
    cout << "Weekly salary: ";
    cin >> salary;
} //end of getSalary

void calcFedTaxes(double salary, double FWT_RATE, double FICA_RATE, double &fwt, double &fica)
{
    fwt = salary * FWT_RATE;
    fica = salary * FICA_RATE;
}  //end of calcFedTaxes

void calcNetPay(double salary, double fwt, double fica, double &netPay)
{
    netPay = salary - fwt - fica;
} //end of calcNetPay 

void displayInfo(double fwt, double fica ,double netPay)
{
    cout << "FWT: " << fwt << endl;
    cout << "FICA: " << fica << endl;
    cout << "Net: " << netPay << endl;
} //end of displayInfo
```

Comment: Please 1- Format you code properly (I tried but it's definitely too borked to be easily fixed) and 2- please ask a more more concise question that doesn't require to read through 100 lines of code.

Comment: **WILL SOME MODERATOR PLEASE** edit this and format the code properly?!!!

Comment: The title is completely different from the actual question.

Comment: didnt you ask this same exact question earlier ang got shot down for "plz send teh codez"?>

Comment: Out of pure curiosity - why C++ for this?

Comment: @Nate Couldn't you? Editing has been made available to all users.

Answer (score 3):

It's because your call to `displayInfo()` is **outside** of the while loop.  So it will only be called that one time.  You need to move it into the loop and call it with the appropriate parameters there.

Comment: Similarly, the other methods need to be called within the loop as well to recalculate the other values (fica, netPay, etc).

Comment: why did you get rid of FWT.. & would i put everything outside the loop inside the while loop?

Comment: That was accidental when I was fixing the formatting of the rest of the code. As for the method calls, yes, they should go inside of the loop. The variable declarations can/should stay outside of the loop.

Comment: Okay! Thanks I figured it out